# Would re-writing this code in PL/SQL be faster than preforming 3 for-loops in Python & how would I transform this?

Tags: python, for-loop, plsql, trino

I have a query that outputs:

1. location number: lct_nbr
2. fiscal week end date: fsc_wk_end_dt
3. item number: itm_nbr
4. product number: pg_nbr
5. SUM(quantity): qty
6. localtimestamp: refresh_date

and I am trying to determine item penetration, or weight. Can these for loops be done with PL/SQL? I am not very familiar with the concept. Would it be faster than doing this in Python? It takes many many hours...

```
item_penetration_by_units = pd.read_sql_query(query, trino_conn)

item_penetration_by_units['total'] = math.nan
item_penetration_by_units['weight'] = math.nan 

LCT_NBRs = item_penetration_by_units['lct_nbr'] 
LCT_NBRs = LCT_NBRs.drop_duplicates()
LCT_NBRs = LCT_NBRs.reset_index(drop=True)  
LCT_NBRs = np.array(LCT_NBRs)  

i = 0 
    for i in range(len(LCT_NBRs)):
        x = item_penetration_by_units.loc[item_penetration_by_units['lct_nbr'] == LCT_NBRs[i]]
        print("i: " + str(i) + " and LCT_NBR: " + str(LCT_NBRs[i]))
        PG_NBRs = x['pg_nbr'] 
        PG_NBRs = PG_NBRs.drop_duplicates()
        PG_NBRs = PG_NBRs.reset_index(drop=True)  
        PG_NBRs = np.array(PG_NBRs)  
        n = len(PG_NBRs)
        j = 0 
        for j in range(n):
            y = x.loc[x['pg_nbr'] == PG_NBRs[j]]
            print("j: " + str(j) + " and PG_NBR: " + str(PG_NBRs[j]))
            WK_End_DTs = y['fsc_wk_end_dt'] 
            WK_End_DTs = WK_End_DTs.drop_duplicates()
            WK_End_DTs = WK_End_DTs.reset_index(drop=True)  
            WK_End_DTs = np.array(WK_End_DTs)  
            m = len(WK_End_DTs)
            k = 0 
            for k in range(m):
                z = y.loc[y['fsc_wk_end_dt'] == WK_End_DTs[k]]
                index = z.index
                indx = index.values
                z = z.reset_index(drop=True)
                total_k = float(z.qty.sum())
                l = 0 
                for l in range(len(z)):
                    item_penetration_by_units.loc[indx[l], 'total'] = total_k
                    if (float(z.loc[l, 'qty']) == 0 and total_k == 0):
                        item_penetration_by_units.loc[indx[l], 'weight'] = 0.0
                    else:
                        item_penetration_by_units.loc[indx[l], 'weight'] = float(z.loc[l, 'qty']) / total_k
```

Each *itm_nbr* has a unique *qty*, *lct_nbr*, *pg_nbr* and *fsc_wk_end_dt*. Weight is calculated by dividing the **qty** a particular item number has by the **total qty** (which is the qty sum for all the item numbers in that particular product group at that particular location for that particular week).

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (with example data and results)

Comment: (Side note: you do not need to initialize the loop variable before a `for` loop.)  (Also, you can say `for lct in LCT_NBRs:` and `for y in PG_NBRs:` and `for k in WK_End_Dts:`.  ANY TIME you write `for x in range(len(y)):`, you can replace that with something that iterates the collection directly.)

Comment: Have you done the math?  You have 4 nested loops here, so the number of inner loops is likely very, very large.  Storing individual items using `.loc` is not the fastest method.  Can't you collect the results in a simple list, then plop the whole list into your dataframe at the end?  `pandas` is not really helping you here, and it is very large.  You are just using it as a place to store things, not to do analysis.  There are better ways to store things.

Comment: Let me see if I can restate your problem.  For each (lct_nbr, fsc_wk_end_dt, pg_nbr), you want to compute the sum of all qtys to get the total per "product group", and then divide the qty for each itm_nbr in that group by the sum?  You ought to be able to do that with pandas grouping.  Let me ponder.

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in Trino.

Comment: @TimRoberts Got it okay! Yes, I am working with a lottt of data so the whole thing takes about 30 hours, defiantly looking for a better solution. & yes, that is what I am trying to do, correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think you can do all of this with a `.groupby`, `.sum`, and a division.  The key to that is making a multi-field index using location, date, and product group.  And given this, yes, I believe you could do the same thing in SQL, although this seems pretty slick.

```
import pandas as pd
import math

# lct fsc_wk_end_dt pg_nbr itm_nbr qty

data = [
   [ 1, '2023-08-01', 1, 1, 5 ],
   [ 1, '2023-08-01', 1, 2, 6 ],
   [ 1, '2023-08-01', 1, 3, 7 ],
   [ 1, '2023-08-01', 2, 1, 2 ],
   [ 1, '2023-08-01', 2, 2, 3 ],
   [ 1, '2023-08-01', 2, 3, 4 ],
   [ 1, '2023-09-01', 1, 1, 1 ],
   [ 1, '2023-09-01', 1, 2, 2 ],
   [ 1, '2023-09-01', 1, 3, 3 ],
   [ 1, '2023-09-01', 2, 1, 9 ],
   [ 1, '2023-09-01', 2, 2, 8 ],
   [ 1, '2023-09-01', 2, 3, 7 ],
   [ 2, '2023-08-01', 1, 1, 3 ],
   [ 2, '2023-08-01', 1, 2, 6 ],
   [ 2, '2023-08-01', 1, 3, 9 ],
   [ 2, '2023-08-01', 2, 1, 7 ],
   [ 2, '2023-08-01', 2, 2, 4 ],
   [ 2, '2023-08-01', 2, 3, 1 ],
   [ 2, '2023-09-01', 1, 1, 2 ],
   [ 2, '2023-09-01', 1, 2, 4 ],
   [ 2, '2023-09-01', 1, 3, 2 ],
   [ 2, '2023-09-01', 2, 1, 9 ],
   [ 2, '2023-09-01', 2, 2, 8 ],
   [ 2, '2023-09-01', 2, 3, 5 ]
]

item_penetration_by_units = pd.DataFrame( data, columns = ['lct','fsc_wk_end_dt','pg_nbr','item_nbr','qty'] )
print(item_penetration_by_units)

item_penetration_by_units.set_index(['lct','fsc_wk_end_dt','pg_nbr'],inplace=True)
x1 = item_penetration_by_units.groupby(['lct','fsc_wk_end_dt','pg_nbr']).sum()
item_penetration_by_units['total'] = item_penetration_by_units.join( x1, how='left', rsuffix='x')['qtyx']
item_penetration_by_units['weight'] = item_penetration_by_units['qty']/item_penetration_by_units['total']
item_penetration_by_units.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(item_penetration_by_units)
```

Output:

```
    lct fsc_wk_end_dt  pg_nbr  item_nbr  qty
0     1    2023-08-01       1         1    5
1     1    2023-08-01       1         2    6
2     1    2023-08-01       1         3    7
3     1    2023-08-01       2         1    2
4     1    2023-08-01       2         2    3
5     1    2023-08-01       2         3    4
6     1    2023-09-01       1         1    1
7     1    2023-09-01       1         2    2
8     1    2023-09-01       1         3    3
9     1    2023-09-01       2         1    9
10    1    2023-09-01       2         2    8
11    1    2023-09-01       2         3    7
12    2    2023-08-01       1         1    3
13    2    2023-08-01       1         2    6
14    2    2023-08-01       1         3    9
15    2    2023-08-01       2         1    7
16    2    2023-08-01       2         2    4
17    2    2023-08-01       2         3    1
18    2    2023-09-01       1         1    2
19    2    2023-09-01       1         2    4
20    2    2023-09-01       1         3    2
21    2    2023-09-01       2         1    9
22    2    2023-09-01       2         2    8
23    2    2023-09-01       2         3    5
    lct fsc_wk_end_dt  pg_nbr  item_nbr  qty  total    weight
0     1    2023-08-01       1         1    5     18  0.277778
1     1    2023-08-01       1         2    6     18  0.333333
2     1    2023-08-01       1         3    7     18  0.388889
3     1    2023-08-01       2         1    2      9  0.222222
4     1    2023-08-01       2         2    3      9  0.333333
5     1    2023-08-01       2         3    4      9  0.444444
6     1    2023-09-01       1         1    1      6  0.166667
7     1    2023-09-01       1         2    2      6  0.333333
8     1    2023-09-01       1         3    3      6  0.500000
9     1    2023-09-01       2         1    9     24  0.375000
10    1    2023-09-01       2         2    8     24  0.333333
11    1    2023-09-01       2         3    7     24  0.291667
12    2    2023-08-01       1         1    3     18  0.166667
13    2    2023-08-01       1         2    6     18  0.333333
14    2    2023-08-01       1         3    9     18  0.500000
15    2    2023-08-01       2         1    7     12  0.583333
16    2    2023-08-01       2         2    4     12  0.333333
17    2    2023-08-01       2         3    1     12  0.083333
18    2    2023-09-01       1         1    2      8  0.250000
19    2    2023-09-01       1         2    4      8  0.500000
20    2    2023-09-01       1         3    2      8  0.250000
21    2    2023-09-01       2         1    9     22  0.409091
22    2    2023-09-01       2         2    8     22  0.363636
23    2    2023-09-01       2         3    5     22  0.227273
```

Comment: I keep getting **ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!** @TimRoberts

Comment: Is your data not sorted?  The `groupby` assumed the indexed columns are sorted (as a group).